# Tab bar not working when clicking second tab

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am having a problem with my Tab bar controller! Upon simulation of my project, my tab bar controller appears, with the first tab selected, and showing the view that I have put in the first tab (so that is all correct). But when I click on the second tab, it takes me back to xcode and displays "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" at the top of the AppDelegate class. I have no idea why this is happening other than maybe something isnt linked correctly. **Can someone go over the steps to link a View Controller to the second tab of a tab bar controller?** Thanks!

All I have in my storyboard of the second Scene is two labels, a switch, a slider, and a button. Because I only need to worry about the values of the switch and the label, those are the only two things I have connected to my code using outlets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Tab Bar Controller with one View Controller**

[image]

**2. Add Second View Controller with UILabel**

[image]

**3. Ctrl + Drag from Tab Bar Controller to Second View Controller**

[image]

**4. Choose from `Relationship Segue` -> `view controllers`**

[image]

**5. Your Tab Bar Controller with two View Controllers**

[image]

**6. Result**

[image]

**7. To access labels etc., create a file for the second view controller, in this example `SecondViewController.swift` which inherits from UIViewController**

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

}
```

**8. In the storyboard with the second view controller selected, set the `custom class` in the `identity inspector` and hit return**

[image]

**9. To connect your ui element to the file and access it, ctrl + drag e.g. from the uilabel to the file and give it a name, in this case `randomTextLabel`**

[image]

**10. Change the label in `SecondViewController.swift` e.g. in the `viewDidLoad`**

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var randomTextLabel: UILabel!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    randomTextLabel.text = "Changed Label Text"
  }
}
```

**11. Result with the changed UILabel**

[image]

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm. No idea what was stopping the first view controller from working but I just deleted it and followed these instructions and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, glad that I could help you!